# Scroll to move to next set of views in Recycler view in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a horizontal recycler view that displays dates. I can scroll it back and forth horizontally to view the dates.

I am looking for an option where when user snaps I show next set of dates.

Example , if the dates shown are : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Upon snapping once, I want to see the next set : 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/PagerSnapHelper?hl=en) or [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html).  Your use case is the sort of thing these were designed for.